# How to combine the sorting of two arrays into one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to combine this sort code for two models into one?
I have two model, Author and Book.

I get Author and Book data, sorted it, and in the end I concat this two data.

```rb
sorted_author = author.sort do |a, b|
  if a.name.nil? || a.amount.nil?
    -1
  elsif b.name.nil? || b.amount.nil?
    1
  else
    [a.name, a.amount] <=> [b.name, b.amount]
  end
end

sorted_book = book.sort do |a, b|
  if a.data.nil? || a.price.nil?
    -1
  elsif b.data.nil? || b.price.nil?
    1
  else
    [a.data, a.price] <=> [b.data, b.price]
  end
end

sorted_author.concat(sorted_book)
```

The problem is that the date will be sorted separately, I need two arrays to be sorted as one.

I can do something like this.

```
author.concat(book).sort_by do |a|
  if a.instance_of? Author
    [a.name, a.amount]
  else
    [a.data, a.price]
  end
end
```

But if here, for example, the name, date, price are nil, then the sorting will end with an error.

Comment: Your existing code puts all books (sorted) after authors (sorted.) If you `concat` upfront, how do you expect `["Orwell", 100]` to be placed compared to `[2019 Sep 06, 50.00]`?

Comment: This reeks of a [X&Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should most likely be sorting the records in the database and not plucking them out and doing it in ruby which does not scale. I would encourage you to focus less on your current solution and provide an example of the models and data and the desired output.

Comment: @max what makes you think there is the database _ever_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate the functionality you have (all authors, sorted, on top of all books, sorted,) you might use that `nil` is `falsey` in ruby.

```
author.concat(book).sort_by do |a|
  if a.instance_of? Author
    [1, a.name || -1, a.amount || -1]
  else
    [0, a.data || -1, a.price || -1]
  end
end
```

Note that I put leading `1` for authors and `0` for books to preserve all the authors come before all the books.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don’t need to keep the current functionality. I just still need to combine all the data and then do the sorting.
I think **"|| -1"** will solve the problem.